# How do I create a db file in pycharm?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, pycharm, kivy

How do i create a db file in pycharm so that it can be used with sqlite3 like this?:
def on_start(self):
# Connect to database
self.connection = sqlite3.connect("example.db")
self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

Comment: Check the documentation (e.g. from std library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) It has examples and much more

Comment: There is no mention on how to specifically create a db file only how to connect it. Do you know how to upload a mysql datbase to github so it can be used with my code. So it  can be used like this.

Comment: def on_start(self):
        # Connect to database
        self.connection = mysql.connector.connect(
            host='localhost',
            user='root',
            password='*******!',
            port='3306',
            database='python_video1'
        )
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

Comment: You are right, and I'm also confused that such page have no more such documents. Just connect, and it should create the database for you. The `:memory:` should hints that database is autocreated, but nothing explicit. If you can file a bug to python, it would be great.

Comment: Hey I got it! Thanks alot. Are you by any chance familiar with buildozer? I am getting an error when i just keep getting # Waiting for application to start when I run buildozer android debug deploy run. If you are can you help me please? I have been stuck for weeks.

Comment: I don't know if PyCharm has functions to create databae. Normally you use execute() with  `SQL` query  like `CREATE TABLE ...` and you should search it any tutorial for SQL.